# Comparison of time until absorption for two absorbing Markov chains

Tags: markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

Let $\{X_t, t \geq 0\}$ and $\{X_t', t \geq 0\}$ denote two markov chains on the same state space $\{1, ..., n+1\}$ with transition probability matrices $P$ and $P'$ respectively. Suppose that both chains have one absorbing state, namely state $n+1$ (the same for both chains). Let $Q$ and $Q'$ denote the transient parts of $P$ and $P'$ respectively. Suppose that $Q$ and $Q'$ satisfy $\sum\limits_{k=1}^j Q_{ik} \geq \sum\limits_{k=1}^j Q'_{ik}$ for each $i,j = 1, ..., n$. I want to show that for each state $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, the expected times until absorption for both of the chains, denoted by $\mathbb{E}T_i$ and $\mathbb{E}T_i'$ respectively satisfy $\mathbb{E}T_i \geq \mathbb{E}T_i'$.

I think this is true, but struggle with the proof. My idea was to use the Neumann series expression of the expected hitting times:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[T] = (I-Q)^{-1}[1, 1 \dots 1]^T= (\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} Q^k)[1, 1, \dots, 1]^T
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[T'] = (I-Q')^{-1}[1, 1 \dots 1]^T= (\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} Q'^k)[1, 1, \dots, 1]^T
\end{equation}

I think it is possible to show that the row sums of $Q'^k$ are upper bounded by those of $Q^k$ for each $k$, but at this point I'm getting stuck.

Ideas are very much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the definition of the transient part?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This conjecture is false in general. E.g., suppose that $n=3$,
$$Q=\frac1{10}
\begin{bmatrix}
 3 & 5 & 2 \\
 2 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix},\qquad 
Q'=\frac1{10}
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & 0 & 7 \\
 1 & 1 & 4 \\
 4 & 2 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
(so that
$$P=\frac1{10}
\begin{bmatrix}
 3 & 5 & 2&0 \\
 2 & 2 & 3&3 \\
 4 & 5 & 1&0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0&10 \\
\end{bmatrix},\qquad 
P'=\frac1{10}
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 & 0 & 7&1 \\
 1 & 1 & 4&4 \\
 4 & 2 & 4&0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0&10 \\
\end{bmatrix}.)$$

Then all the conditions on $Q$ and $Q'$ hold. However,
$$ET_1=\frac{442}{51}\not\ge\frac{615}{51}=ET'_1.$$

---

Here is an informal explanation for this example: We have two Markov chains: a $P$-chain, with transition matrix $P$, and a $P'$-chain, with transition matrix $P'$. For both chains, the state space is $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and the absorbing state is $4$. In both chains, only from state $2$ it is possible to get to the absorbing state $4$ (with a nonzero probability) in one step. Moreover, in the $P'$-chain it is impossible to get to $2$ from $1$ in one step, whereas in the $P$-chain this can be done with probability  $5/10$. So, in the $P'$-chain, we can only get to $2$ from $1$ by first visiting state $3$. Also, in  the $P'$-chain, the probability of getting to $2$ from $3$ in one step is only $2/10$, whereas this probability for the $P$-chain is $5/10$, which latter is substantially greater than $2/10$. All this suggests that it is harder (and hence takes longer on the average) to get from $1$ to $2$ (and hence from $1$ to the absorbing state $4$) in the $P'$-chain than to do so in the $P$-chain.

The above example just shows that the comparison described informally in the last paragraph is compatible with the conditions imposed in the OP.

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much!